# Revalidate Data - Next js - Prisma - ServerSide

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, app-router

I'm trying to have an automatic refresh of the data in a serverside page. in next js app folder.
Since my page is serverside i havn't made an API for it and im using prisma request directly in the page. Now im trying to have this page to be refresh of its data everyminutes since the purpose of the page is to show a scoring table.

```
export default async function page() {
  const data = await prisma.events_list.findMany();

  if (data) {
    return (
      <main className="w-full sm:w-[700px] px-4">
        <Tabs defaultValue="01" className="my-8">
```

I want to avoid using react useEffect and having to switch to an API call.
I'm not sure it is possible to do so.
Without it...

any inputs?

i have tryed to set a timer in an other client side componant but it would reload the entire page.